# The left operand of '&' is a garbage value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I wouldn't normally paste an image, I would provide the code as text, but I felt that the analyzer warnings where important.

I'm not sure what this means and how to fix the problems.

[image]

The full code can be found here
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Core/Categories/DDData.m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you can expand the warning in the sidebar to get a detailed list of the control flow that leads to this situation. In your case, the static analyzer is saying that, given a certain set of circumstances, that line of code will execute where `inbuf[1]` has never been initialized to a value, and thus is garbage.

I would guess that the circumstances are if `ch == '='`, this will set `flendtext` to `YES`, which will set `ixinbuf` to `3`, which means that `inbuf[x]` for x == 0-2 will never be initialized, and the subsequent access of these values is garbage.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I'm confused as to how to proceed :(

Comment: @Jules: Rewrite the code such that it doesn't depend on garbage values.

Comment: @Jules: Your question was what the analyzer warning meant. That's been answered. The question of how to fix the broken logic in your code is different. What is your code expected to do with the input `"d="` (e.g. one character before the `=`)? Make sure it does that. Because it looks like it won't do that correctly as-written.